# square bullet list wrong font size with body css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list in my sidemenu, the settings don't seem to read past the css of the .body class in stylesheet -

```
ul.develop 
{
list-style-type:square;
color: #FFF;
margin:0;
padding:0;
margin-top:0.6cm;
}



li.develop
{   
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: normal;
color:#fff;
}
```

My body class is -

```
body {
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

The list then is defaulting to body class 12px, if I change body to 11px, the list is fine but I want to keep 12px for actual body of main content of copy on site.

I tried using !important but unsure that is correct?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your HTML code too.

Comment: Are you sure the selector: `li.develop` is correct? That it shouldn't be: `.develop li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have `.develop` on `ul` not `li`, try putting your font rules on the `ul.develop` rule as they will apply to the `li`'s underneath.

```
ul.develop 
{
    list-style-type:square;
    color: #FFF;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:0.6cm;

    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed .li as it wasn't useful and put all in .ul - this worked fine - there were no links in list anyway - tx again

Answer (score 0):

Put your 'body' related CSS above/ before the other styles. It reads it top down. Hope that works!

Comment: I believe it does read top down, however `li.develop` is more specific than `body` for that element and therefore `li.develop` would be selected.